# If I replace a character in a text file with the same character, does the Checksum change?

Tags: file, checksum

Say you have a text file with the only contents being plain text and CR, LF, etc.  If you replace one of those characters with the same exact character.  Will this result in a new Checksum?

Comment: No, it is the same file, therefore the same checksum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

According to google a checksum is:

> a digit representing the sum of the correct digits in a piece of stored or transmitted digital data, against which later comparisons can be made to detect errors in the data.

An easy way to verify this would be to use a checksum calculater like the one found here: 
http://www.online-tech-tips.com/cool-websites/what-is-checksum/ and then conduct the experiment by actually replacing a character with the same character.

The case where it might seem like it does change the checksum is when visually similar but actually different characters are used, ie: tabs vs spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is a simple text file and was opened with an editor that does not track changes in that particular file, then no, the checksum **will** remain the same.

Check out this resource for more information: [Checksum Examples, Use Cases and Calculations](https://www.lifewire.com/what-does-checksum-mean-2625825)